show which of a list of filenames do not exist in a given list of directories
I have a long list of filenames like 20231121_150111.jpg... in a text file (one filename per line).
And another list of directories. Those directories contain files.
How can I check and show which files from my list do not exist in any of the directories?
: edit
filenames.txt :
20230326_163243.jpg
20230326_163244.jpg
20230326_163245.jpg
....

createt with "ls -1"
directories.txt :
./2017/2017_3/DSC_0559.JPG
./2017/2017_3/DSC_0067.JPG
./2017/2017_3/DSC_0195.JPG
....

createt with "find ./ > directories.txt"
if i run the script in bash
#! /bin/bash -
readarray -td '' missing < <(
  export LC_ALL=C
  comm -z -23 <(<filenames.txt tr '\n' '\0' | sort -zu) \
              <(<directories.txt tr '\n' '\0' |
                  sort -zu |
                  find -H -files0-from - -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -printf '%f\0' |
                  sort -zu
              )
)
if (( ${#missing[@]} )); then
  printf '%s\n' "Couldn't find:"
  printf ' - %s\n' "${missing[@]}"
fi

i see a lot of output of:
 - 20230716_103851.jpg
 - 20230716_103852(0).jpg
 - 20230716_103852.jpg
....

are my filenames and directories wrong ? or what do i wrong ?
i have a folder with many subfolders amd pictures in it.
i have an other folder with many jpg files.
most of the jpg files are in subfolder, but not all.
i need a way to show which are not in the subfolders
filenames.txt : many jpg files
directories.txt : the subfolders with the most of the files in it

well you go through the lines, one by one, and check whether the file exists. We love to help people understand how to write shell scripts, but we're not a free shell script writing service – could you explain what you've tried and where you're stuck? This is really not too complex a problem to come up with an approach!

It's a lot easier in zsh:
If you have your list of file names in filenames.txt and list of directories in directories.txt:
#! /bin/zsh -
typeset -U expected=( ${(f)"$(<filenames.txt)"} )
typeset -U   actual=( ${(f)^"$(<directories.txt)"}/*(ND:t) }
missing=( ${expected:|actual} )
if (( $#missing )) print -rl "Couldn't find:" ' - '$^missing

With bash, you can do something approaching if you're on a recent GNU system with:
#! /bin/bash -
readarray -td '' missing < <(
  export LC_ALL=C
  comm -z -23 <(<filenames.txt tr '\n' '\0' | sort -zu) \
              <(<directories.txt tr '\n' '\0' |
                  sort -zu |
                  find -H -files0-from - -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -printf '%f\0' |
                  sort -zu
              )
)
if (( ${#missing[@]} )); then
  printf '%s\n' "Couldn't find:"
  printf ' - %s\n' "${missing[@]}"
fi


Leaving aside the consideration that a file MIGHT be in the wrong directory, and assuming you are starting with a list of JUST filenames/not paths, then the most efficient solution would be to get a list of the filenames which you have (I'd use find ... -basename {} \; for this) sort that, sort the list of of files you expect and compare them using diff.
(Sorry @Marcus Müller - running a new search for each file is not a very economical solution)

no need to apologize, because you're 100% right regarding efficiency of searching for each file individually; it's just not what I recommended ;) Thing is that you can gather the file list once (bash array ( * ), then filter that for regular files) and then just check within that.

Assuming no newlines in file names, this is probably all you need:
readarray -t dirs < yourdirs
comm -23 <(sort -u yourfiles) <(find "${dirs[@]}" -type f -printf '%f\n' | sort -u)

assuming yourfiles contains your list of file names and yourdirs contains your list of directory names.

Also assumes directory names don't start with - and don't match the name of some predicates, and a locale with a total order, and GNU find for -printf.

Note that -type f means all files with a type other than regular are excluded. Without -maxdepth 1 it also finds regular files in subdirectories. Unless you add -H, that will not look into those directories that are listed by one of the symlinks to them.

@StéphaneChazelas thanks for the notes. I assumed the OP did want to search in subdirectories.
